# 'save_model' method + 'save_as = True' // how to change "old" object

Tags: django, django-admin

I have the following model and i am using 'save_as' in admin.py to enable a “save as new” feature on admin change forms.

The goal is that if i use 'save_as' the "old" object should have set the boolean field 'hide' to True.

I tried to implement the ModelAdmin method 'save_model' to admin.py but this only changes the value for the "new" object.

Is it possible to change the "old" object also?

**models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    hide = models.BooleanField(default=0)
```

**admin.py**

```
class personAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    save_as = True

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.hide = True
        super(personAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    # Get old object's id from the url
    old_obj_id = resolve(request.path).args[0]
    # Now that we know the id, we can easily fetch it from database
    old_obj = Person.objects.get(id=old_obj_id)
    # Update it's hide field        
    old_obj.hide = True
    # Don't forget to save it!
    old_obj.save()

    # Now we can save the new object as a new one (save_as)
    super(personAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```